# Linux x64 Disassembly: single movzwl operand question

Tags: linux, x86-64

A quick question regarding a `movzwl` instruction which do not behave as I expected.

here is the disassembled code:

```
movzwl (%rax),%eax
```

Before the instruction, `rax` is `0x7fffffffe410` and point to `0x5`
After the instruction, I would expect `eax` to be `0x5` (which is the case), but I would not expect that the upper bits of `rax` be cleared too... However, when debugging, `rax` values `0x5`...

I thought that `movzwl` would only clear the upper bits of `eax`, but not the `rax` ones. Could you explain?

Thank you very very much for your help!

[image]

Comment: "I thought that ..": Did you check the official Intel documentation?

Answer (score 1):

This is a somewhat tricky part of the x64 instruction set and is not mentioned in descriptions of individual instructions but only as a sidenote in the general introduction section. Here's a good answer on it:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177137/why-do-x64-instructions-zero-the-upper-part-of-a-32-bit-register